# Autocomplete v Nearby Search?

Tags: google-places-api, google-nearby, google-places-autocomplete

I am building an app that will require extensive use of the autocomplete function and have currently implemented under Nearby Search. I recently learned however that this is the priciest option given its high cost + associated Contact and Atmospheric data imposed costs.

I am therefore looking for a good option to get relevant autocomplete search results based on the users location without the need for 'Nearby search'. I care about the UX and thus want to avoid people scrolling too much to find a place near them. The only field I need is name & potentially address.

I tried Nearby search, if I understand correctly this is the only way to get autocomplete predictions based on where you physically are located - I have now learned that this is too expensive however

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Autocomplete is actually good enough for the predictions of the address, but it highly depends on user input. Nearby search is used for searching nearby places given a coordinate/placeID, not for predicting user input. Can you try updating your question that includes a sample of what you tried doing? You can check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you better in constructing your question. And also so that the community could help you better.

Comment: Please do note that Autocomplete is actually free when you use session tokens. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/session-tokens And also please include what programming language or library you are using as your question could potentially be deleted for lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

**Autocomplete** and **Nearby Search** are entirely different operations and APIs, you *can* combine both to build a user-friendly experience but they each play a very different role.

[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) provide *predictions* of places based on the user's **input**, i.e. characters the enter into an input field. These predictions can be biased, even restricted, to a small area around the user's **location**, to increase the chances that they will represent places near to the user. Depending on whether places far away from the user are acceptable or useful, or not, you can use one or the other:

- [`locationbias`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#locationbias) if predictions far away are acceptable and useful, e.g. a user searching for a place that is not necessaraly where they are, or in situations where the user location is either not available or not very precise, e.g.

  - user wants to find a place to go to
  - user location is obtained from geolocating their IP address
  - user location is obtained from geolocating their cell towers
- [`locationrestriction`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#locationrestriction) if only **very** nearby predictions are acceptable **and** user location is known to be very precise (e.g. GPS or other high-precision sources). This would make sense in mobile applications when the user location is provided (by the phone's OS) with a small radius (e.g. under 100 m.) **and** the user really just wants to find places that describe where they are now. Even then, beware that some places can be bigger than you'd expect, e.g. airports include runways.

**Note on billing**: Place Autocomplete *can* be free under specific conditions: when your application implements session tokens **and** there is a Place Details request at the end of the session, in which case [Place Details is billed and Autocomplete is not](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session). However, even if your application implements session tokens, each time a user *doesn't* pick a prediction, Autocomplete is billed as a [session without Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-no-details-session). And in the simpler case, if your application does not implement session tokens, *all* Autocomplete is billed as [per-request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-per-request) (and Place Details is billed separately, on top of that).

[Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) can provide **nearby** places (and can [`rankby=distance`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#rankby)) based on **only** the user's location and **without** user's input. This can be used to show an initial list of places (e.g. the nearest 5 places) even before the user starts typing. There a few caveats:

- results depends **heavily** on the user location being very precise
- results will only include `establishment` places, i.e. business, parks, transit stations

If you'd want addresses instead of businesses, you could use [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding) instead of Nearby Search, with the caveat that this can return results that are *near/ish* and don't necessarily represent the exact place where the user is at. This is more useful when you want to find *addresses around a location*; they may include the actual address of that location, but that is not guaranted.